# Oracle Decide if two result sets are identical

Tags: sql, oracle

I am attempting to determine if two result sets are identical in a query.

**MINUS** is not a viable solution as the act of **set_a minus set_b** will remove both instances of 1 from the result.

This is a simple test script that demonstrates the use of **INTERSECT** to make that decision.  Expect "Set A is bad", and "Set B is good"

```
with 
set_a as
(
    select 1 x from dual union all -- Some silly result set with some duplicate data
    select 2 x from dual union all
    select 1 x from dual
), 
set_b as
(
    select 1 x from dual union all -- Another silly result set to compare against
    select 2 x from dual 
),
set_i as
(
    select * from set_a    -- What is common between those two sets
    intersect
    select * from set_b
),
diffs as
(
    select (select count(*) from set_a) a_count, -- Get the size of each set
           (select count(*) from set_b) b_count,
           (select count(*) from set_i) i_count
    from dual
)
select a_count, i_count, -- check whether a and i are the same size
       case a_count - i_count
           when 0 then 'Set A is good'
                  else 'Set A is bad '
       end case
from diffs

union all

select b_count, i_count, -- check whether b and i are the same size
       case b_count - i_count
           when 0 then 'Set B is good'
                  else 'Set B is bad '
       end case
from diffs
;
```

**Are there any other approaches that might be used to solve this?**

Similar - [Compare two SQL queries result sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32658781/compare-two-sql-queries-result-sets)

Comment: Perhaps a FULL OUTER JOIN and verify no (unexpected) NULL values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function so that you have unique rows in each set and then `FULL OUTER JOIN`:

```sql
WITH set_a (x) AS (
  select 1 from dual union all -- Some silly result set with some duplicate data
  select 2 from dual union all
  select 1 from dual
), 
set_b (x) AS (
  select 1 from dual union all -- Another silly result set to compare against
  select 2 from dual 
),
unique_a (x, rn) AS (
  SELECT x, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x ORDER BY ROWNUM) FROM set_a
),
unique_b (x, rn) AS (
  SELECT x, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY x ORDER BY ROWNUM) FROM set_b
)
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN a.rn = b.rn THEN 1 END) AS num_identical_in_a_and_b,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN a.rn IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS num_not_identical_in_a,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN b.rn IS NULL THEN 1 END) AS num_not_identical_in_b
FROM   unique_a a
       FULL OUTER JOIN unique_b b
       ON (a.x = b.x AND a.rn = b.rn)
```

Which outputs:

| NUM_IDENTICAL_IN_A_AND_B | NUM_NOT_IDENTICAL_IN_A | NUM_NOT_IDENTICAL_IN_B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 0 | 1 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9cWNez2a)

Comment: This appears to work.

Answer (score 2):

One simple solution that I have used in the past:

- Calculate `a except all b`
  This gives you **all items in a that are not in b**... but this is not enough!
- Calculate `b except all a`
  This gives you **all items in b that are not in a**
- `union all` both of the results
  If the final result is empty, both sets are equal

This approach compares all columns of all rows; you can even compare the rows `(1, 'foo', 'bar')` with the row `(1, 'foo', 'baz)`.

```
select * from (
    select * from a
    except all
    select * from b
) a_only

union all

select * from (
    select * from b
    except all
    select * from a
) b_only
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pgrpAesw)

Comment: You basically rewrite this 2 days old [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76743063/4808122) using the ANSI SQL syntax, right?

Comment: Yup. Didn't read all the answers.

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH set_a AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS ID, 'John' AS Name FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS ID, 'Jane' AS Name FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS ID, 'Mike' AS Name FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS ID, 'Sarah' AS Name FROM dual
),
set_b AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS ID, 'John' AS Name FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS ID, 'Jane' AS Name FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS ID, 'Mike' AS Name FROM dual
)
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM set_a) AS a_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM set_b) AS b_count,
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM set_a) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM set_b) THEN 'Good'
        ELSE 'Bad'
    END AS result
FROM dual;
```

| A_COUNT | B_COUNT | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 3 | Bad |

```
WITH set_a AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS ID, 'Apple' AS Fruit FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS ID, 'Banana' AS Fruit FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS ID, 'Orange' AS Fruit FROM dual
),
set_b AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS ID, 'Apple' AS Fruit FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS ID, 'Banana' AS Fruit FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS ID, 'Orange' AS Fruit FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS ID, 'Kiwi' AS Fruit FROM dual
)
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM set_a) AS a_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM set_b) AS b_count,
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM set_a) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM set_b) THEN 'Good'
        ELSE 'Bad'
    END AS result
FROM dual;
```

| A_COUNT | B_COUNT | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 4 | Bad |

```
WITH set_a AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS ID, 'New York' AS City FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS ID, 'Los Angeles' AS City FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS ID, 'Chicago' AS City FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS ID, 'Houston' AS City FROM dual
),
set_b AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS ID, 'New York' AS City FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 2 AS ID, 'Los Angeles' AS City FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 3 AS ID, 'Chicago' AS City FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 4 AS ID, 'Houston' AS City FROM dual
)
SELECT 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM set_a) AS a_count,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM set_b) AS b_count,
    CASE 
        WHEN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM set_a) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM set_b) THEN 'Good'
        ELSE 'Bad'
    END AS result
FROM dual;
```

| A_COUNT | B_COUNT | RESULT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 4 | Good |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/tGCaS6ME)

Comment: For your test cases, you need to have at least 1 duplicate data row in set_a.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with `Oracle Database 21c` you may use [`MINUS ALL`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/The-UNION-ALL-INTERSECT-MINUS-Operators.html#GUID-B64FE747-586E-4513-945F-80CB197125EE) which is exact what you need (i.e. minus *without de-duplication*).

```
select * from set_a
MINUS ALL
select * from set_b
;

         X
----------
         1

select * from set_b
MINUS ALL
select * from set_a
;
no rows selected
```

If *both* queries return *no rows* than the row sources are *identical*.

And yes, also starting with `21c` you may use instead of the *non standard* `MINUS ALL` the standart keyword `EXCEPT ALL`.